# python extend or append a list when appropriate

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to append a list if X is a string, but extend it if X is a list? I know I can simply test if an object is a string or list, but I was wondering if there is a quicker way than this?

Comment: The quickest and simplest way is to write code that doesn't force you later to do this.

Comment: Not possible in this particular circumstance, I'm inheriting X from a backend system and it won't pass single objects as list items

Comment: "it won't pass single objects as list" Sad.  And you can't wrap it with a sensible function or extend it with extra methods or subclass it to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mylist.extend( [x] if type(x) == str else x )`

or maybe the opposite would be safer if you want to catch things other than strings too:

`mylist.extend( x if type(x) == list else [x] )`

Comment: I forgot about isinstance(), which would probably be more flexible than type()

Comment: Used the second of these, work pretty well, and is a little quicker than using ifs - my thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. `extend` takes any iterable as input, and strings as well as lists are iterables in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer = ["str", [1, 2, 3], 4]
myList = []

for x in buffer:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        myList.append(x)
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        myList.extend(x)
    else:
        print("{} is neither string nor list".format(x))
```

A better way would be using `try-except` instead of `isinstance()`